# What's the purpose of a wire from stud to outside?

Tags: drywall, grounding, fireplace, wire, home-theater

On a couple of my studs there is a small gauge wire that seems to go through the outside wall to the outdoors (into the flue cavity) as shown in the picture. What is its purpose?

This is on the wall above a fireplace where a TV was hanging. (Thus the tags for the question.)

[image]

Comment: When you say “outside” do you mean outside the stud cavity?  Not outdoors?

Comment: I would guess that they're stabilizing the flue?

Comment: @Tyson Into the flue cavity (I edited the question to reflect that).

Comment: I think this is to add some support to the brick work, I.E. keep the bricks from moving away from the  framed wall. I an not sure so it is not in the answer section.